# Hostname resolves to wrong IP address

Tags: ip, ping

When I ping the hostname of my phone from a RaspberryPi (with Raspbian installed), it resolves to the wrong IP address:

```
pi@raspberrypi ~ $ ping isimon.fritz.box
PING isimon.fritz.box (192.168.178.153) 56(84) bytes of data.
From raspberrypi.local (192.168.178.221) icmp_seq=1 Destination Host Unreachable
```

Actually the IP address is 192.168.178.218, not ...153
How do I solve this?

Thanks

Comment: Are you using a real DNS server or an entry in `/etc/hosts` either way, you'll have to find the source of name resolution and fix it there.

Comment: @Eric I haven't edited anything inside the hosts file, so I assume it's using a DNS server...

Comment: You can look in /etc/resolv.conf to see what it's using for a DNS server then, and then get on that machine and figure out where it's actually doing its DNS config

Comment: I think there is one entry in the fritz box. Can you check that and fix it to the wanted ip-address?

Comment: @ott-- Hmmm.. I restarted the 'multid' daemon on the fritzbox (recommended on a few posts), which should clear the dns cache, but it seems like it didn't do anything;

before, the output of `host isimon.fritz.box` was something like 
`isimon.fritz.box has address 192.168.178.153
isimon.fritz.box has address 192.168.178.218`, but now it just prints the first IP address, so now it *only* outputs the wrong IP (there's no sign of a .218 IP in the DNS config files)

Comment: What DNS server are you using? How is your phone DNS record defined?

Comment: Concretely, what's the output of `dig isimon.fritz.box`?

Answer (score 2):

```
sudo service ssh restart
```

This does it for me. Host resolves correct IP later on. A better and easier way is to assign static ips so your dns lookup doesn't get all messed up.